# pass var to function() js with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just looking for the best practise way of doing this.
I have a table listing information and in the last column is a button with "Edit/View". When the user clicks on the button a div area appears with more information which can be edited

Code below with some fragments of jstl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Click on Edit/View on table
$('.viewCustomer').click(function()
{
    .......
});

</script>

<tr class="odd">
  <td>${customerBean.comName}</td>
  <td>${customerBean.comCode}</td>
  <td class="noRightPad"> <input type="submit" name="createBut" value="View/Edit" class="viewCustomer" /> </td>
</tr>
```

So my question would be:

(1) how do i pass a variable to function $('.viewCustomer').click(function()

(2) is this the best way of going about to do this. Is there a more efficient/secure/cleaner of doing this?

Cheers
Alexis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click function will not be called by you. It is called when the button is clicked, and as such has the event object passed to it:

```
$('.viewCustomer').click(function(evt){
    .......
});
```

What exactly are you wanting to pass? You can access the DOM element that you are clicking using `this` and `$(this)`, so maybe it possible to reference what you want from here.

**EDIT For comment**

> if the user clicked on the button that
>   was in the 4th row of the table and in
>   that row the another colum had
>   customer id 1234 i want to pass the
>   variable 1234.

*NOTE: None of the below has been tested, but ought to suffice*

Let's assume your 'customer id' column has a classname of 'customerid'. So your HTML might be:

```
<tr class="odd">
  <td>${customerBean.comName}</td>
  <td class="customerid">${customerBean.comCode}</td>
  <td class="noRightPad"> <input type="submit" name="createBut" value="View/Edit" class="viewCustomer" /> </td>
</tr>
```

The jQuery might look something like:

```
$('.viewCustomer').click(function(){
    var $buttonCell = $(this).parent(); //the <td> containing the button
    var $buttonRow = $buttonCell.parent(); //the <tr> containing the button and your customer id
    var $customerIdCell = $buttonRow.find("td.customerid");
    var customerId = $customerIdCell.text();
});
```

The above is proken down into lines to show you how stuff is being retrieved. Using 'chaining' we can express it more concisely:

```
$('.viewCustomer').click(function(){
    var customerId = $(this).parent().parent().find("td.customerid").text();
}
```

You can also search for the customerid cell as a 'sibling' of the button cell for an even more concise approach (and one less function call).

```
$('.viewCustomer').click(function(){
    var customerId = $(this).parent().siblings("td.customerid").text();
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I am looking to pass a string variable. So if the user clicked on the button that was in the 4th row of the table and in that row the another colum had customer id 1234 i want to pass the variable 1234.

cheers
alexis